# How to calculate the position of a small rectangle which is inside other rectangle on web?

Tags: jsp, itext

I have a  resizable image which is inside the rectangle on web, i want to export the rectangle and re-sized image to PDF but PDF rectangle will be 16 times smaller than the rectangle which is on web, plz let me know how to adjust the position of image in PDF with 16 times smaller rectangle?

Comment: What is a resizable image? Aren't all images resizable if you don't care about resolution? Also: you are exporting a rectangle on the web (which format? and more specifically: which measurement system?) to PDF (the measurement system uses user units; by default 1 inch = 72 user units). You aren't showing us any code and it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: hi Bruno thanks for replaying, as i said i have a rectangle on a Web which is 16 times bigger than the rectangle on PDF, i want to adjust the image position in small rectangle which is 16 times smaller. i only want a logic to position the image in small rectangle.

Comment: You are repeating your question without adding any measurement units. You don't specify what you mean by "rectangle on a Web". I didn't vote to close the question in the hope that you'd clarify, but as you didn't, I'll cast my vote.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found solution. now i am able to adjust image.